# How to set up a hex grid of links in HTML?

Tags: html

I run a D&D campaign made up of lots of small worlds, each touching 6 others, as in a hex grid. In fact, my (sloppily) hand drawn map is done on a hex grid printout.

What I'd like to do is make essentially an index page, with each little world having its own html page.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the links on that index page stay in a hex grid layout.

I suppose I could do it all by hand in CSS, but that seems rather tedious, as I have about 300 different hex worlds.

Any idea on how to expedite the process? The best I can think up right now is having a generic Javascript function, that's called by each and every hex as it's loaded to the page, which would orient it at the correct position.

Comment: @lbu: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_map), I believe.

Comment: Can't think of a non-tedious way to do that in html/css - using canvas might be a better option.

Comment: @ibu a "grid" of hexagons: http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/tess/bighex.gif

Comment: I was looking at something similar a while ago, but went direct to SVG and ignored HTML. Maps aren't something that HTML is very good at describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with a `map` and `area` elements.  You can use `poly` for the shape, and do it up that way.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea, and I'll get right on trying it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but I'll wager you can use a CSS transform to do 6 consecutive 60 degree rotations around your center point.

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/FMpc9/

(Note: Requires a webkit browser, should be easy to update to Moz.)